# OpenGL texture not displayed (solid color instead texture) or displayed with artifacts

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl, textures

I'm using code to draw text as textures in OpenGL (Qt4.8.3 + Linux (debian-like)).
Code was ported from 2D project, where it is working good.

2D project was using gluOrtho2D, now I use gluLookAt for 3D.

The issue is that instead of text I'm seing colored rectangle.
If I turn on GL_DEPTH_TEST I see artifacts instead of text. BTW artifacts change if I move camera, which is quite strange.

[image: issue]

Here's the code:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL() {
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); //Set blending function.
    glEnable(GL_BLEND); //Enable blending.
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glPushMatrix();

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 60.0f, (GLdouble) width() / (GLdouble) height(), 0.001f, 10000.0f );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Set up current camera
    gluLookAt( cameraDistance * sin(cameraTheta * M_PI / 180) * cos(cameraPhi * M_PI / 180),
               cameraDistance * sin(cameraTheta * M_PI / 180) * sin(cameraPhi * M_PI / 180),
               cameraDistance * cos(cameraTheta * M_PI / 180),
               0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
               0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glTranslatef(-4.5355, -4.5355, 0.0);
    glPushMatrix();

    // draw text labels
    drawLabel(1, 0, 90, "1");
    drawLabel(2, 0, 90, "2");
    drawLabel(3, 0, 90, "3");
    drawLabel(4, 0, 90, "4");
    drawLabel(5, 0, 90, "5");

    glPopMatrix();

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);

    glPopMatrix();
}

void GLWidget::drawLabel(float xpos, float ypos, float angle, char *txt) {
    float labelHeight = 0.3;
    float labelWidth = labelHeight / 2;
    float margin = labelWidth / 10;
    float len = (float) strlen(txt);

    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(-angle, 0, 0, -1);
    glTranslatef(xpos, ypos, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, -1);
    glScalef(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glTranslatef(- len * labelWidth / 2, -labelHeight / 2 + margin, 0.0f);

    // background
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-margin, -margin, 0);
    glVertex3f(len * labelWidth + margin, -margin, 0);
    glVertex3f(len * labelWidth + margin, labelHeight + margin, 0);
    glVertex3f(-margin, labelHeight + margin, 0);
    glEnd();

    // text
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, glFont->getTextureID() );
    glFont->drawText(labelWidth, labelHeight, txt);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPopMatrix();
}

void oglFont::drawText(GLfloat cw, GLfloat ch, char *txt)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    //character location and dimensions
    GLfloat cx = 0.0f;
    GLfloat cy = 0.0f;

    //calculate how wide each character is in term of texture coords
    GLfloat dtx = float(c_width) / float(m_width);
    GLfloat dty = float(c_height) / float(m_height);

    for (char * c = txt; *c != 0; c++, cx += cw) {
        int index = getCharIndex(c);
        int row = index / c_per_row;
        int col = index % c_per_row;

        if (index < 0) {
            //qDebug() << "glFont: Character outside of font! char: " << c;
        }

        // find the texture coords
        GLfloat tx = float(col * c_width) / float(m_width);
        GLfloat ty = float(row * c_height) / float(m_height);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(cx, cy);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(cx + cw, cy);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(cx + cw, cy + ch);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(cx, cy + ch);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that because texture was loaded in QGLWidget constructor, context was either not created or not set.

I moved texture loading in initializeGL() method and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the artifacts is Z fighting.

This problem can be solved by increasing the depth buffer precision OR by making the different objects further apart from each-other  (the ones from drawlable ).

Also make sure that your generated text doesn't get culled by the far plane / near plane (maybe you generate the geometry very near the edges ? ).

Comment: Tnx for the tip. I draw black rectangle before drawing texture.

Comment: Tnx for the tip. I'm drawing black rectangle before drawing texture. Removing black rect solves issue with artifacts, so you are right about depth issue. But I'm still seeing no text from texture, but gray rectangles... In other words texture is not displayed, instead rectangle is painted with solid color.

Comment: Well, should't u use tx , ty instead of 1,0 and 0,1 in your glTexCoord2f ? I mean , you are giving for each quad the whole texture .

Comment: yep, actually i do. trying to find what leads to the issue i tried to display whole texture.

changed it back to tx and ty, no change

Comment: Maybe you have an empty texture or something. Try the following debugging approaches : hardcode uvs (so don't compute them) so you display only 1 letter (the same letter, regardless of the wanted character). If you still don't get the expected results, change your texture to a full red texture and see that indeed you are using the correct texture (you should see red blocks instead of your grey ones).

Comment: As already mentioned, the same code and the same texture works fine in another project. The only difference is that I use gluOrtho2D there.

Comment: Did you do the test I mentioned and got good results ? Orth2D has effect on how you see things - is a projection matrix. If you see a quad instead of a letter, then it's a texturing problem (or maybe you don't make alpha tests ).Try the approach above. Furthermore, try replacing a test character's surrounding background with a solid color instead of transparency (to check if the problem comes from transparency).

Comment: It turns out that because texture was loaded in QGLWidget constructor, context was either not created or not set. I moved texture loading in initializeGL() method and it works great.